# Git diff produces whitespace output only

Tags: git, git-diff, meld

I am trying to diff some changes I have done, with git diff. The output produced though is a bunch of empty lines with no text in there. Like in the example:

```
$ git diff myfile.java





$
```

When I am doing a diff with meld though, I am getting the results as expected. I am using git version 2.8.1. Any ideas?

Comment: hm.. unicode/utf8/etc encoding issues in myfile.java vs. your terminal? Does it happen on all files or on just that one only? what happens when you `cat` that file to the console?

Comment: Working fine with cat

Comment: That's quite bizarre.  What does `git status` (or `git status --short`) show?

Comment: Git status shows the modifications as expected too